# Hide top bar icons on one montior only

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, icons

I couldn't find a question like this, which might be because I don't have a clue how the top bar icons are named properly.

I am using 2 monitors and Ubuntu 12.04 with the standard interface (Unity 3D?). I got it to look like I want it to, but the icons on the right of the top bar are shown on both monitors.

Is it possible to hide the icons (power icon, etc.) on one monitor only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area your talking about has about 50 names these days but I think you mean the notification area, the spot where all the indicators are?

If so, then no. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1749696&page=2 for other people with the same request.

Comment: Well, its not a big problem, it was rather aesthetical. Thanks for the answer!